# Error exporting data with TOAD for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, export, toad

Hi I'm trying to export a data result from a query, but my export result looks like this:

```
Insert into MyTable
   (att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7)
 Values
   (1, 203, 'Myname' 
    'Y
Y   
L   
N',
NULL,
NULL,
NUL);
```

Instead of getting my chars values in the right place I get them in that form, the colon is missing so Oracle thinks that I'm inserting 'YYLN' instead of 'Y', 'Y','L', 'N'.  and I get a NULL values instead of my real value. When I do my query it shows my cvalues in the right place. How can I correct this bug?

Comment: But the fourth column is having the values ending with `chr(10)`. The seven columns are having seven crresponding values, so what is your question? Please show your desired output.

Comment: thats the insert that toad give me when i export the data from my query, it give me that specific insert stament with those exact syntax errors, the missing colon error, that casue the columns to mismatch and since that query returns 1200 rows i cant find and replace all the errors since the char value is not always the same

Answer (score 0):

Insert queries work like this:

```
insert into table
(field1
, field2
, field3
, etc)
values
(value1
, value2
, value3
, etc)
```

Note that after the first field/value combination, each one is preceded by a comma.  Now look at the insert query in your question.  Count the number of commas in the field list and the number of commas in the value list.  They have to be the same.